# What does 1일 1떡 mean?

Tags: translation

**What does 1일 1떡 mean?**

Is it something about food or what? I tried reading an article, but I did not understand the context because of this wording.

Comment: Depends on where you found the expression... 떡 is sometimes used as a slang for sex - the expression might be saying "have sex every day."

Comment: What article are you talking about? Please provide link or post the contents, or post more context

Comment: Without context it is hard to pinpoint it's meaning (especially since I only recently learning the language). But It'd say it suggest you should eat a rice cake everyday.
But once again this is a literal translation and might mean something else as @jick pointed out

Answer (score 2):

말은 아주 많은의미를 가집니다
1인1떡이란

말그대로의의미
하루에 하나의 떡을가지거나 먹을수 있다

말에 숨어있는의미
하루에 두개이상의 떡이나 물질적인 무언가를 가질수없다
하나의 떡 혹은 하나만 가질수 있다

예시
오늘 회사에서 일을하면서 이런말을들었다
오늘은 식사할때 1인1떡이니 참고해주세요
그래서 일을 끝내고 식당으로 갔다
사람들은 떡을나눠주고 있었고 한사람당 하나의 떡을 받았다
나는 떡을 더 줄수 없는지 물어봤고 떡은 하나만 준다고 했다

예시2
오늘 회사에서 일을하면서 이런말을들었다
이제부터 식사할때 1인1떡이니 참고해주세요
그래서 일을 끝내고 식당으로 갔다
사람들은 떡을나눠주고 있었고 한사람당 하나의 떡을 받았다
나는 떡을 더 줄수 없는지 물어봤고 앞으로(계속해서)하루에 떡은 하나만 준다고 했다

한국인20대청년

Words have so much meaning
What is 1 person, 1 rice cake?

literal meaning
You can have or eat one rice cake a day.

Hidden meaning in words
You can't have more than two pieces of rice cake.
You can't  only have one rice cake

example
I heard this while working at the company today.
Please note that today's meal is one rice cake per person.
So I went to the restaurant after work.
People were handing out bread, and each person received a rice cake.
When I asked him if he wanted more rice cake, he said he would give me one more rice cake.

Example 2
I heard this while working at the company today.
From now on, only one rice cake is allowed per person for meals, so please refer to it.
So I went to the restaurant after work.
People were handing out rice cakes, and each person received a rice cake.
When I asked him if he could give me more rice cakes, he said he would only give me one a day from now on (and from now on).

Korean young man in his 20s